# Help Me: Loading Qt dialogs from python Scripts

Tags: python, qt, dialog, editing, signals

im a novice into developing an application using backend as Python (2.5) and Qt(3) as front end GUI designer. I have 5 diffrent dialogs to implement the scripts. i just know  to load the window (main window)

```
 from qt import *
    from dialogselectkernelfile import *
    from formcopyextract import *
    import sys
    if __name__ == "__main__":

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        f = DialogSelectKernelFile()

        f.show()
        app.setMainWidget(f)
        app.exec_loop()
```

main dialog opens on running. i have a set of back,Next,Cancel buttons pusing on each should open the next or previous dialogs. i use the pyuic compiler to source translation.how can i do this from python. please reply i`m running out of time.i dont know how to load another dialog from a signal of push button in another dialog.  Help me pls
Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def displayNextForm(self):          
    self.close()
    self.extr=FormMakeImage(self,"FormMakeImage",1,Qt.WStyle_DialogBorder)
    self.extr.exec_loop()
def displayPrevForm(self):
    from DialogSelectFile import *
    self.close()
    self.ext=DialogSelectKernelFile(self,"SelectKernel",1,Qt.WStyle_DialogBorder)
    self.ext.exec_loop()
```

This did work smooth. I was able to implement the Next back feature. Possible warnings are occuring on Imports. but no problem on running.
  Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting the button click signals to handler functions?

If you are able to get one dialog to open, getting the other dialogs to open should be as simple as instantiating the new dialog and calling the .show() method in the first dialog's button handler.

Maybe you could upload your code somewhere so we can see more of it.  What you have above doesn't really help much.

Comment: thank you for that answer. how ever i could solve it by adding by instancing the next window by obj=WinName(self,"name",1,WStyle_DialogBorder) and obj.exec_loop()
 i hav anothr qstn to put up.following here.pls try to help me if u can. thanks again